# How to avoid git auto creating a .pack file?

Tags: git

In a big project.

```bash
cd project
git init 
git add .
ls .git/objects/pack # big pack file
```

If I want to unpack .pack, I need to run `git unpack-objects < .git/objects/pack/pack-.pack` every time after `git add .`.

How to avoid git auto cteate .pack file?

I hope git just create .pack when I run `git repack` or `git gc`

I already tried `git config gc.auto 0`,but git still create pack file if repo > 3GiB.

Comment: First, please use punctuation and capitalization appropriately to help make what are trying to say as clear as possible. Second, have you done any research regarding whether or not packing is a required step or if you can avoid it, how that would be done. Please EDIT your question to add information to it and to make it more clear.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Aren’t the `.git/objects/pack` a default part of Git? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: it's big project. i want to run  `git repack`  only if i need.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is not generally possible.  You can configure `gc.auto` to disable `git gc`, which will prevent Git from repacking loose objects periodically.  However, in some cases, such as a bulk checkin, Git will always create a pack file because that's more efficient and more effective than writing a large number of loose objects.

In general, it is frequently more efficient and more performant to store data in pack files than in loose objects, so Git does that in certain cases.  Notably, if you have a large number of loose objects, enumerating objects can become pathologically slow due to having to read many objects out of a directory listing.  Because of this, there are certain operations, like bulk checkin and some types of fetches, where Git will maintain or create a pack file because the alternative is very poor performance, and the developers didn't wish to add options that were only useful for people who wanted to make their repositories unusably slow.

Git doesn't *always* write pack files because for a small number of objects, writing loose objects can be faster.  However, as the number of loose objects grows, it's important to repack periodically.

None of this functionality prevents you from running `git repack` only when you want to do so or to disabling automatic garbage collection; it only serves to store data in the most efficient way given the operation in progress at the time.